# Show that series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{3}e^{-t n^{2}+1} $ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the following converges:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^{3}e^{-t n^{2}+1} $$

where $t$ is a parameter.

Comment: what is $\alpha$ here?

Comment: Presumably $t>0$, or else is a complex number with positive real part?

Comment: t is real number

Comment: the exponential decreases faster then any polynomial can grow....

Comment: Well the series (obviously) doesn't converge for $t\le 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $t>0$ then $e^{-tn^2 +1} < n^{-5}$ for sufficiently large $n$ (it is true for any negative power), i.e. for $n>M$.

Now

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3e^{-tn^2 +1}=\sum_{n=1}^{M} n^3e^{-tn^2 +1}+\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty} n^3e^{-tn^2 +1}$$

Note that it is enough to show that the second component is convergent . And by the choice of $M$:

$$\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty} n^3e^{-tn^2 +1}<\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty} n^3\cdot n^{-5}=\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}n^{-2}$$

It is well known that the last series is convergent as a piece of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Thus the original series is convergent because $e^{-tn^2 +1} > 0$.

Note that for non-positive $t$ this is not true. For example for $t=-1$ obviously

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3e^{n^2+1}=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps, first showing that $\sum n^3\exp(-tn)$ is convergent with the Ratio Test, and then comparing your series to this very favorably with  a direct Comparison Test.
Naturally, $t$ must be positive for all this to work.